# What are the correct equations for the frequency of a photon along kerr geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, frequency, kerr-metric

As a photon orbits close around a Kerr black hole in an elliptical orbit that reaches into its ergosphere, the frequency of the light ray should increase due to frame-dragging. Given that:

$$
v = f \lambda_0
$$

And the [equation for the angular speed](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-frame-dragging.762986/) of an object in the ergosphere of a black hole is:

$$
\omega=\frac{2Mrac}{\Sigma^2}
$$

Where:

$$
\Sigma^2=(r^2+a^2)^2-a^2\Delta \sin^2\theta
$$

$$
\Delta= r^{2}+a^{2}-2Mr
$$

And:

$$
v = r\omega
$$

Therefore:

$$
f = \frac{2Mr^2 ac}{\Sigma^2 \lambda_0}
$$

Since $f \propto r^2$, this suggests that as the light ray enters the ergosphere, $f$ would increase as expected, but once it leaves the ergosphere, its frequency would decrease. However, it makes sense that the higher-energy photon in the ergosphere would continue having a higher energy, and thus higher frequency, even after it leaves the ergosphere - after all nothing takes away energy from it after it leaves the ergosphere. In effect:

[image: Frequency comparison graphs]

The key question for me is why there is this discrepancy, and whether my provided frequency equation is even the correct equation for the frequency.

Comment: The photon has mass zero and its frequency is only through the value of its energy, E=hnu .

Comment: That only happens if you take [superradiant scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superradiance#Astrophysics_and_relativity) (for which you need quantum electrodynamics and it depends on the initial frequency) into account, otherwise the photon's total energy (kinetic plus potential) is a conserved quantity.

Comment: @Yukterez Would you happen to know the form of the frequency equation taking into account superradiant scattering? I'd assume it involves some complicated solving of the Klein-Gordon equations to find $\psi$ and then using $\psi$ to find the frequency?

Comment: In the [source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269319307488) I know of and the references therein it doesn't sound like there's a unique or exact way to do it

Comment: @Yukterez Alright, I'll figure it out, thanks for the help